# ruby pandoc convert html string to docx temp file

Tags: ruby, pandoc

Using the ruby pandoc gem, I'm trying to convert an html page as a string ("...") to a temp docx file, that users of the site can then download.

The documentation for pandoc ruby says to use:

```
PandocRuby.html("<h1>hello</h1>").to_latex
```

I assume this works for docx as well, although this is the output

```
PandocRuby.html("<h1>hello</h1>").to_docx

"PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x02\x00\b\x00\xF8.\x7FF\x8E\r\x16\xD8]\x01\x00\x00$\x06\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00[Content_Types].xml\xB5\x94\xCBN\xC30\x10E\xF7|E\xE4-J\xDC\xB2@\b5\xE9\x82\xC7\x12*Q>\xC0u&\xAD\x85_\xB2\xA7\xAF\xBFg\x92\xD0\b\xA1*\xA9h\xBB\x89\x94\xCC\xCC\xBD\xC7W\xE3L\xA6;\xA3\x93\r\x84\xA8\x9C\xCD\xD98\e\xB1\x04\xACt\xA5\xB2\xCB\x9C}\xCE_\xD3\a6-n&\xF3\xBD\x87\x98P\xAF\x8D9[!\xFAG\xCE\xA3\\\x81\x111s\x1E,U*\x17\x8C@z\rK\xEE\x85\xFC\x12K\xE0w\xetc...."
```

Just creating a new file

```
File.open(yourfile, 'w') { |file| file.write(docx_conversion) }
```

throws encoding errors, but I didn't think it would work because docx files are zipped doc and xml files.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
File.open(yourfile, 'wb') { |file| file.write(docx_conversion) }
```

Setting the file mode to `wb` tells Ruby that you will be writing unencoded binary data and sets the binary data encoding as the external encoding.

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I can't give different type of styling in pandoc like font color and all?